# One to one realationship with ormlite

Tags: ormlite, one-to-one

How to implement one to one table relationship in Ormlite? Let’s say I have entities **Country** and **Capital**.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "countries")
public class Country {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField
    String name;

    public Country() {
    }

}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "capitals")
public class Capital {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField
    String name;

    public Capital() {
    }

}
```

Is it true that I need to have this field in **Country** class?

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
Capital capital;
```

...and this field in **Capital** class?

```
@DatabaseField
Country country;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need the @DatabaseField in the class which the table contains the foreign key.

If **countries** contains **capital_id**, then you should add

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "capital_id", foreign = true)
private Capital capital;
```